# How to check if element was shown in cypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I have a problem with cypress + react.

I have a situation where I Request data from EP after blurring of input and it will show a message that the data is validating, the message disappears right after the request is done.

I have to test that message is visible after input blur but it disapears so fast that cypress can't detect it / not assert it

part of test code:

```
  cy.get('.some-input').type('some-value')
  cy.get('body').click(); // hacky way to blur from input
  cy.get('.message')
    .contains('Please wait whilst we validate your details')
    .should('be.visible');
```

part of react code:

```
{accountNumberValidationInProgress && renderMessage(t('Please wait whilst we validate your details'))}
```

so `accountNuberValidationInProgress` is true when I blur from some input and the request started, after I receive data from EP this variable is set again to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can first check for the toast message to be visible and then not to be visible.

```js
cy.contains('Please wait whilst we validate your details').should('be.visible')

cy.contains('Please wait whilst we validate your details').should(
  'not.be.visible'
)
```

Comment: It will fail on first be.visible because cypress will make assertion it is not visible because it shows and hides very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to freeze-frame the app with `cy.clock()`. It should work if the toast is using `setTimeout()`.

```js
  cy.clock()

  cy.get('.some-input').type('some-value')
  //cy.get('body').click(); // hacky way to blur from input
  cy.get('.some-input').blur()
  
  cy.tick(100)  // tick 100ms, also try other times

  cy.get('.message')
    .contains('Please wait whilst we validate your details')
    .should('be.visible');
```

---

**Delaying request**

Since the toast is controlled by a `request`, try adding an intercept with delay.

```js
  cy.intercept(url-of-request, (req) => {
    req.on('response', (res) => {
      res.delay(1000)                // allow time for toast to show
    })
  })

  cy.get('.some-input').type('some-value')
  cy.get('.some-input').blur()
  
  cy.get('.message')
    .contains('Please wait whilst we validate your details')
    .should('be.visible');
```

Comment: Sorry for not being precise, it is not toast with setTimeout, it's just an element that shows after blur and hides after the request is done.

`renderMessage(text)` just return element with css class `.message` and  textNode `text`

Comment: Ok, was my bad assumption. Then it's even easier - add an intercept with a `delay` option to slow down the request. But somehow, I think the premise is wrong - I would expect the `.contains('Please wait whilst we validate your details')` to complete a lot faster than a request can return.